# Detect available css values for a specific property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cross-browser

**Are there any function, library or anything else can detect values of css properties?**

Take "*position*" for an example, use some methods then I can get "*absolute*", "*static*", "*relative*" ... are "*position*"'s values.

So I can detect the supporting degree of a css property. 
And how many values for this property I can use.

Thanks very much!

Comment: If my guess is right, you wanted to know the possible values for a particular css property.. right?

Comment: `document.getElementById('your element').style` returns all of your current styles to that particular element..

Comment: Just look here, the best compatibility tables for support HTML and CSS: http://caniuse.com/

Comment: I'm sorry. Maybe I describe it unclearly. I mean the value of the property. "caniuse.com" just the compatibility data of the property. But it can't tell me the details for each properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, you wish to iterate over the possible values for a css property.  Unfortunately, there is no way to do this.  What you could do is store the possible values so that when you need to list them, you can just look them up.  Take the following example.

```
var cssProperties = { position: ['inherit', 'static', 'relative', 'absolute', 'sticky', 'fixed'], float: ['inherit', 'left', 'right', 'none'] };

function lookupCssValues(property) {
    return cssProperties[property];
}
```

You can traverse the possible css properties for an element by doing something like this:

```
for(var property in element.style) {
    if(typeof elem.style[property] === 'string') {
        console.log(property) // this is a css property for the element
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, I think you got the point. 
I hope there some ways to do this.
Indeed, no way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with jQuery!

```
$('.element-in-question').css('position');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h7KHT/

Comment: I'm sorry. Maybe I describe it unclearly. I mean the possible values for a property. Not the values I set.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.someelement').css("position")
```

Comment: I'm sorry. Maybe I describe it unclearly. I mean the possible values for a property. Not the values I set.